# Regression coefficient overestimated in full model

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have constructed a linear regression model in `R` using the `lm` function.  I was hoping someone could explain to me why when I run my full model I get an overestimate of the categorical variables.  For instance, the intercept - I understand that this means the Biomass when all `continuous variables = 0` but also when it is compared to the `reference reef (Admiral Reef)` and the `reference season (Fall)` and the `reference species (O. annularis)`.

[image]

However, when I run a model with just the categorical variables I get a totally different estimate (and one that is closer to the actual values).

[image]

Here are the means for the whole dataset

[image]

Comment: Curious on why I was down voted - I searched the site and have found no understandable answers

Comment: Questions about the interpretation of a statistical analysis belong on [stats.se], not Stack Overflow because they are not specific programming questions.

Comment: @MrFlick Apologies - anyway I can migrate it over so I do not duplicate?

Comment: It it gets enough votes it may get migrated (it's at 4/5 now, but there's no guarantee it will happen). You could also just delete the question here and repost it there.

Comment: The regression coefficient for, say, `O. faveolata` (the value in the `Estimate` column) is the predicted difference in `Biomass` when the species is `O. faveolata` relative to when the species is  `O. annularis`, with all other variables held fixed. That coefficient (and all the other coefficients) will in general be different between your two models because the first model controls for many more variables than the second model.

Comment: @eipi10 But why would the intercept be so high for the full model?  It seems way out of the range of the `biomass` values.

Comment: Try keeping all the continuous variables except for the 6th-order polynomial in Time; I suspect the handling of the Time variable might be leading to some confusion here.

Comment: The intercept in a linear regression is equal to $\overline{Y} - \overline{X_1}\hat{\beta}_{1,OLS}-\overline{X_2}\hat{\beta}_{2,OLS}-\ldots$.  The intercept adjusts so that the estimated regression line passes through the mean of the data.  Suppose you include a new variable in a regression and that the new variable has a negative coefficient and a positive mean (to make things easy, assume the other coefficients are not affected).  That will move the line down, on average.  The intercept will adjust up to keep the line going through the middle of the data.

Comment: A model with a sixth degree polynomial is almost always overfitting. You could try modelling the time effect with a penalized smoother or you could use a time series model.

Comment: I did remove the polynomial for time and the coefficient did go down a bit but still seems a little high.  @Roland I will try a penalized smoother.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to compare raw group means against the intercept or coefficients in this type of regression with an unbalanced design and multiple predictors. To illustrate, compare your model with only the categorical variables against the overall means for your 3 species. The intercept of 7.42 is already somewhat below the group mean of 8.05 for the reference `O.annularis`. The difference of 3.17 in raw group means between `O.faveolata` and `O.annularis` is very close to the coefficient of 3.29 for `O.faveolata`, but the difference of -1.52 between group means of `O.franksi` and `O.annularis` is quite different from the `O.franksi` coefficient of -0.09. These discrepancies presumably represent different associations of the 3 species with the other categorical predictors.

This problem will be exacerbated in your model that includes the continuous predictors, as small differences among the species in values of the continuous predictors, near their observed non-zero values, will be magnified in the extrapolation down to values of 0 for the continuous predictors that are required to provide the intercept in this formulation of the problem. You could presumably examine the relations of all continuous predictors to the individual species to understand the detailed reasons why the intercept seems to be so high to you, but that might not be worth the effort. Try instead expressing each value of a continuous predictor as its difference from its overall mean value; I suspect that your distress over the apparent discrepancies will be greatly alleviated.

Finally, please get further expert guidance on how best to deal with your `Time` variable. A 6th-order non-orthogonal polynomial is probably not the best way to proceed, and it's not clear from the limited data description here how `Time` and `Season` would best be considered together for your model.